# Get Key Press Action

Tags: java, android

In some phone we have the option in which we can state if power button locks the screen or just switches off the back light. I was wondering if there's a way to get the keypress action because as far as my understanding goes, they are just changing the actions in power key press event.

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can listen `SCREEN_ON` and `SCREEN_OFF` intent when power button press. Else what you want to know?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);//prevent phone from being locked
}

@Override 
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

 if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER)
    {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
                    //do something 
            }

            else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
                    //do something
            }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: This is when the power key is pressed. Is there a way to know which intent will be passed when I press it it. Not on key press.